# ld: library not found for -lboost_program_options-mt

Tags: macos, gearman

When I install gearmand on mac10.8.3. Everything seems fine when I install libevent boost and so on . But at last I got and error return 1 when I run command make.

Error infomation is :

`make -j5  all-am

CXXLD    bin/gearadmin

ld: library not found for -lboost_program_options-mt

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make[1]: *** [bin/gearadmin] Error 1

make: *** [all] Error 2`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need libboost-program-options-dev (debian name) library - try to find how it's named in MacOS.